# Handling 1280 * 720 [ hd version ] size of Frame in SDL2 how to?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, sdl-2

Is this the right way of creating texture to render 1280*720  [ hd version] image?

I am receiving the packet from RTSP server through ffmpeg, and decoding and getting frame.

To render i  follow the below steps.

```
 SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER);

 screen = SDL_CreateWindow("TEST APPLICATION", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 0, 0,
                    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

bmp = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_IYUV, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 1280, 720);

SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(renderer, 1280, 720);


 while (1)
  {
    Handling SDL Event.    ->
    for (;;)  {
    while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event))
      switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                SDL_Quit ();
                exit (0);
                break;
        case DISPLAY_IMAGE:
                SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(bmp, NULL, pFrame->data[0],
                                     pFrame->linesize[0], pFrame->data[1], 
                                     pFrame->linesize[1],
                                     pFrame->data[2], pFrame->linesize[2]);

                SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, bmp, NULL, NULL);
                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
                break;
          }

  }
```

Also,
From some other thread, i will push the event like:

```
SDL_Event event;
event.type =  DISPLAY_IMAGE;
SDL_PushEvent (&event);
```

Kindly tell me if this is the right practice ?

Comment: `screen = SDL_CreateWindow("TEST APPLICATION", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 0, 0,
                    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);`
Why are you setting size to `0, 0`?

Comment: olevegard, i have been trying with trial and error only. Since Texture size i am providing, i thought i could provide (0,0) for window. Is that wrong? kindly help.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about it. But I would assume it is wrong since it's not mentioned in the documentation. What happens if you print the result of SDL_GetError()?

Comment: I do not get any error, also, even if i change (0,0) to (1280,720),  i dont see any difference. but how to find out if it is the right approach?.